# Refactorise Linq query

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq

I have a LINQ query I am trying to minimise, but I get an error when i try.
Genkai_db is a Entity Framework instance and i query sql table.

This is working:

```
public UNITY_DB_PRODEntities12 Genkai_db = new UNITY_DB_PRODEntities12();


    public List<string[]> Query_FpacInactif()
    {
        List<string[]> li = new List<string[]>();
        List<string> u = Genkai_db.final_full_data
            .Where(x => x.FPAC_TimeStamp > 100)
            .Select(x => x.computername)
            .ToList<string>();
        foreach (string a in u)
        {
            string[] Sarray = new string[] { a, "FPAC" };
            li.Add(Sarray);
        }

        return li;
    }
```

In another similar function I tried to refactor into one line:

```
public List<string[]> Query_McAfeeConsolidation()
{
    List<string[]> li = (Genkai_db.Consolidation_McAfee
        .Select(x => new string[] { x.computername, "McAfee" }))
        .ToList();
    return li;  
}
```

This last function failed with error:

> Unable to initialize the array of type 'System.String []' in a query
>   result. Use 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1 [System.String]'
>   instead.

PS: I tried a lot of things before asking even using `List<string>` over `string[]` but nothing has worked in one line.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show us what your input object looks like, and what exactly you are trying to get out as the result

Comment: Please provide information about the type `Consolidation_McAfee`.

Comment: Why does the first method select over `Genkai_db.final_full_data` and the second one over `Genkai_db.Consolidation_McAfee`? Is this a mistake?

Comment: edited its a entity framework instance

Comment: Linq to Sql queries are *interpreted* and converted to sql.  Linq to Sql doesn't know how to take your query and convert it into a sql query that returns an enumerable of string arrays.  That's a limitation you have to work around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess it is not able to translate it into SQL query, you can bring it back in memory using `AsEnumerable` and project.

Based on your original query you can always filter the records in SQL, pervious query loads entire data in memory which is not good obviously (but wrote that based on your `Query_McAfeeConsolidation` method):-

```
 List<string[]> li = Genkai_db.Consolidation_McAfee
                          .Where(x => x.FPAC_TimeStamp > 100)
                          .Select(x => x.computername)
                          .AsEnumerable()
                          .Select(x => new string[] { x, "McAfee" }))
                          .ToList();
```

Comment: its working so if i understand EF not able to cast in one shot query result to List<string> i have to it in 2 time.

Comment: @Zwan - Yeah it translates the query to SQL and it's provider doesn't support projecting arrays. Or even any other C# method like `String.Join` for example.

Answer (score 3):

This should work

```
return Genkai_db.final_full_data
    .Where(x => x.FPAC_TimeStamp > 100)
    .Select(x => x.computername)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(cn => new string[] { cn, "FPAC" })
    .ToList();
```

This will query the `computername` from the DB and then create the array in memory because the `AsEnumerbale` will transition from EF to Linq-to-objects.

Answer (score 0):

Linq doesn't seem to work well with arrays.

Use  List<List<string>> instead:

```
  public List<List<string>>> Query_McAfeeConsolidation()
  {
      List<List<string>> li = Genkai_db.Consolidation_McAfee
                                       .Select(x => new List<string> { x.computername, "McAfee" })
                                       .ToList();
      return li;
  }
```